# How to write a test to verify if a jetpack composable function's preview works

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Let's assume to have a big project that uses Jetpack Compose and @Preview to display some combinations of views.

For some reason, someone from the team made some changes on Theme therefore the Previews no longer work.

Do you think it is possible to create an automated test to verify whether previews are working (or not)? This test of course should be used on CI.

I googled around but I didn't find any good starting point.

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like you need screenshot tests. I like Paparazzi for this https://github.com/cashapp/paparazzi

Comment: as far as I know I can use paparazzi library to "visually" test a composable function. However, I'm interested in testing whether its preview function does work (compile at least) or not